# DRF @action decorator serializer.data response issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm using @action in my ViewSet.

```
@action(detail=True, methods=('get', 'post', 'put', 'patch'))
def crontab(self, request, pk=None):
    template_obj = self.get_object()

    app_name = template_obj.application.name
    template_name = template_obj.name
    periodic_task_name = '%s:%s' % (app_name, template_name)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        periodic_task = PeriodicTask.objects.filter(
                            name=periodic_task_name)
        if periodic_task.exists():
            crontab_obj = periodic_task.get().crontab
            serializer = serializers.CrontabScheduleSerializer(crontab_obj)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response({'crontab': 'crontab does not exist'})
```

When condition `if periodic_task.exists():` is True and return `Response(serializer.data)` executes I get this error related with TemplateSerializer. This serializer is used in ViewSet, not in my crontab action, and the 'application' field I do not touch in any way.
Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**. Put the logic from @action into a separate view with the same URL + '/your_action_name/'.

Also. Can do something like this in your @action, but this is not entirely correct:

```
if periodic_task.exists():
    crontab_obj = periodic_task.get().crontab
    serializer = serializers.CrontabScheduleSerializer(crontab_obj)
    res_data = {**serializer.data}
    return Response(res_data)
```